Checking a string value in a column and input accordingly between datasets pandas
I have concatenated dataframe


Roll  marks  grade  section  Team.    
 123     56.    Fair.  A.    Titans
> 789     70.    Good.  A.    Kings
> 445     89.    Good.  C.   Giants
> 675     45.    Fair   b.   Boss 

I need to check if the column  dm['grade'] is fair the create a dataset having columns and values as

Final= {'activities': db['team'], 'student': db['roll']}

Else if dm['grade'] is good then return values as
> Final2= {'type': db['team'], 'student': df['marks']}

Example output: if grade is fair
Activities student score
Titans       123

And if good

Activities student score
Rugby       56

I tried
If dm['grade'] is fair:

But not getting correct output. Pls help using python 3.6

Can you please provide the exact expected output(s) for clarity?

@mozway     Example Need output if grade is fair
Activities student score
Baseball    100
And if good
Activities student score
Rugby       8


@mozway the edit is given need out like that.

You first need to concat all dataframes:
united_df = pd.concat([Dm, Db, Ds, Df], axis = 1)

Then filter according to your criteria:
fair_df = united_df[united_df['grade'] == 'fair']
good_df = united_df[united_df['grade'] == 'good']

Then in each dataframe you can remove columns (pd.drop) or rename columns (pd.rename).
To return the result in a dictionary format you can do:
fair_df.to_dict()


Yes I have done that but after that I want use if else condition to return the above mentioned data

@CoderG - see my updated answer above

Example Need output if grade is fair
Activities student score
Baseball    100
And if good
Activities student score
Rugby       8

